# Spoon - read SQL code from txt file and execute on DB

Tags: sql-server, svn, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm learning to develop ETL using Pentaho Spoon, I'm pretty noob yet.

Instead of storing SQL operations inside its file, I'd like to have them on their own .sql files. It makes easier to track changes on Subversion, and in case of need I can just open the sql file on DB manager and execute it directly.

How could I do that? I suppose I could use some component to read a txt file into a variable, and another component to take that variable and execute it on DB.

How's the simplest way to achieve that?

Comment: Have you looked at the `SQL` step at the job level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard SQL Table input, you can define the query to be a parameter `${my_query}` and this parameter has to be defined (without ${...} decoration) in the transformation properties: right-click anywhere, select Properties on the popup menu, the Parameter tab.

Each time you run the transformation, you'll presented the list of parameters, among which my_query which you can overwrite.

To automatize, follow the example which was shipped with the installation zip. In the same directory as you spoon.bat/spoon.sh, there is a folder named `sample`, in which you will find a `job` to `read_all_files` or `read all_tables`. Basically this job list the files in a directory, and for each one puts it in a variable and use it as a parameter to run the transformation. Much more easier to do than to explain.[image]